# Running the same function in loop and saving the outputs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, for-loop

The function `slope()` below generates the random `b` values and the values generated is used to calculate `result` in second function. In first run `slope()` will generate 15 values and calculate `result` for that 15 values and save in dictionary. I want to run this function for 100 times so for each set of 15 values it save the result like `output` for each run. I want to save the iteration number also.  Here I am trying to save in dictionary So that I can save my result later in pandas dataframe. How can run this function 100 times?? How can I save the result so that  later I can convert that result in pandas dataframe easily?

```
import numpy as np


# Randomly generated b values 
def slope():
    b = np.random.uniform(1,2.5,15).round(2)
    return b

def psd(a):
    y = np.random.uniform(1,2.5,2).round(2)
    for i in y:
        result = y**(-a) + 1
    dictionary = {f'{a}':f'{list(result.round(5))}'}
    return dictionary

power = list(psd(x) for x in slope())
```

The output of above function is :

```
[{'2.08': '[1.40189, 1.38618]'}, 
 {'1.19': '[1.41358, 1.35635]'},
 {'2.0': '[1.51757, 1.61035]'},
 {'1.61': '[1.35884, 1.45538]'},
 {'1.07': '[1.38503, 1.80131]'},
 {'1.08': '[1.40485, 1.48885]'},
 {'2.37': '[1.11844, 1.66215]'},
 {'2.45': '[1.14653, 1.20226]'},
 {'1.34': '[1.3748, 1.34766]'},
 {'1.33': '[1.48239, 1.307]'},
 {'2.12': '[1.83302, 1.80152]'},
 {'1.19': '[1.46882, 1.6644]'},
 {'1.65': '[1.35917, 1.2442]'},
 {'1.61': '[1.27493, 1.24591]'},
 {'1.17': '[1.45778, 1.47483]'}]
```

Comment: Start with `[slope() for _ in range(100)]` -- that gets you a list of the results of calling `slope()` 100 times.

Comment: I suppose I didn't understand you clearly. When I call your mention code in power variable and see, I saw it gave me 100 list of 15 slopes. I don't mean this. After generating the slope It should calculate the result too.

Comment: So `[[psd(x) for x in slope()] for _ in range(100)]` maybe?  I'm still not clear on what it is you're trying to actually generate, so I'm trying to suggest things that might get you closer.

Comment: Thank you for asking. I will try this. Actually like I mentioned above, I have generated random 15 number from `slope()`. That 15 numbers are used to calculate the result for formula defined in function `psd()` and after that the result and slope were saved in a dictionary. Now this whole process I want to repeat for 100(say). And save the result for each repeat with repetition number also.

Comment: @Samwise `[[psd(x) for x in slope()] for _ in range(100)]` it did the work but can't know for which loop the `slope()` values and calculation are. I need to save for which loop it did the calcualtion also.

Comment: What is your expected pandas dataframe output? Could you show an example?

Comment: @ Samwise. It would be more easy If this is done by defining a function. That would be great help.

Comment: @ferdy My expected output is `loop number`. Say, 1 , 2,....100. For each loop the the values generated from the `slope()` and for each values generated from the `slope()` it should save result after calculation from fucntion `psd(a)` .

Comment: What I mean is this: `How can I save the result so that later I can convert that result in pandas dataframe easily?` Now I need to know your example pandas dataframe output. What entries are in the columns?

Comment: @ferdy I suppose I can do it by nested dictionary like this: `dictionary = {'loop 1' : {'a': [1,2,3,4,5],
                     'b': [6,7,8,9,1]},

              'loop 2' : {'a': [2,3,4,5,6],
                     'b': [7,8,9,1,2]}}`

Comment: Those numbers have nothing to do with `{'2.08': '[1.40189, 1.38618]'}, ...` from your posted example. Are you not using the value of `power`?

Comment: @ferdy this is just an example. Of course in place of a,b,c I need `slope()` and instead of [1,2,3,4,5] I need result form `psd()`.

Comment: @Samwise instead of calling `[[psd(x) for x in slope()] for _ in range(100)]` can you please tell me how to do it my defining function. So that I suppose I can easily make the nested dictionary and save it as data frame.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking.  If you edited your question to provide an example of what you're trying to produce, it might be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code to call it 100 times.

```
import numpy as np


# Randomly generated b values 
def slope():
    b = np.random.uniform(1,2.5,15).round(2)
    return b

def psd(a):
    y = np.random.uniform(1,2.5,2).round(2)
    for i in y:
        result = y**(-a) + 1
    dictionary = {f'{a}':f'{list(result.round(5))}'}
    return dictionary


# Save power in a dict with iter value as key.
data = {}
for i in range(100):
    power = list(psd(x) for x in slope())
    data.update({i: power})

# print(data)
```